# Local variable in MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an MVC view that displays a list of items. The table that was automatically generated with the view has this action link on every row:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.section_detail_id }).
```

This works fine but my requirement is to allow the user to highlight a row and click on a delete button at the bottom of the list. I need a way for the button to know which row is currently highlighted. So I created this local variable:

```
@{int sectionDetailId = 0; }
```

Then I added an onclick event on the table rows to store the the id of the row that is clicked:

```
tr id="@item.section_detail_id" onclick="addClass(this.id); sectionDetailId = @item.section_detail_id">
```

Here is the button that is supposed to bring up the delete view:

```
input type="button" value="Delete Employee" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Delete", "EmployeeList", new { id = sectionDetailId })'; alert(sectionDetailId)" />
```

The value that is passed to the view is always zero no matter what row is clicked. I added the alert function to the button to show that the variable has the correct value.

Is there a way to get the Action method to use the variable or to get the value from the table in some other way? The Action method works correctly if I hard code an ID.

Here is the complete view:

```
@model IEnumerable<VCPDS2.Models.EmployeeListViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<style>
    tr.highlight {
        background-color: blue !important;
    }
</style>

@{int sectionDetailId = 0; }

<h2>Index</h2>

@*<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>*@

@if (Model != null)
{
<table id="employeeTable" class="table table-responsive table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Last Name
        </th>
        <th>
            First Name
        </th>
        <th>
        Employee ID
        </th>
        <th>
            Phone
       </th>
        <th>
           Budget Unit
        </th>
        <th>
            Division
       </th>

    </tr>
    <tbody id="employeeList">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
        <tr id="@item.section_detail_id" onclick="addClass(this.id); sectionDetailId = @item.section_detail_id">

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.last_name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.first_name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.employee_id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.phone_nbr
                @* @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.phone.area_code) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.phone.phone_nbr)*@
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.BU
               @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.phone.BU)*@
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.description
               @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.department.description)*@
            </td>
            <td>
                @*@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.section_detail_id }) |
                            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.section_detail_id }) |*@

                            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.section_detail_id })
                        </td>
    </tr>
                }
    </tbody>
</table>

<p>
    @*@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")*@
    <input type="button" value="Add Employee" 
 onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "EmployeeList")'" />
    <input type="button" value="Delete Employee" 
onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Delete", "EmployeeList", new { id = 
@sectionDetailId })'; alert(sectionDetailId)" />

</p>

 }

<script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<script>

    function addClass(row) {
        //alert(row);
        $('#employeeList').children().removeClass('highlight');
        var element = document.getElementById(row);
        element.classList.add("highlight");
    }

</script>

@*@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.section_detail_id }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.section_detail_id }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.section_detail_id 
})*@
```

This is the rendered HTML for the delete button:

```
<input type="button" value="Delete Employee" onclick="location.href='/EmployeeList/Delete/0'; alert(sectionDetailId)">
```

Comment: This code: `addClass(this.id); sectionDetailId = @item.section_detail_id` - does not do what you think it does. Look at the **rendered** HTML and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Please post your full `for` or `foreach` loop section (statement and body) because there's insufficient context in your question to give you a working answer.

Comment: What you might want here is to have another form that is wrapped around your delete button.

Comment: Will you edit your question and put the full view instead? It's difficult combining the markup which might end up as a guess.